# Craft 3: get enabled sites of an entry

Tags: entries, craft3, plugin-elementapi, multi-site

I'm looking for a way to list all the enabled sites for a given entry. 
 I couldn't find some sort of `getEnabledSites` method that's similar to the available [`getSupportedSites`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-entry.html#method-getsupportedsites).  The latter only returns the `siteId` and `enabledByDefault` properties.

Note that I'm doing this within the [Element API](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api) plugin.

Comment: Do you want to get all available sites for the element or all sites where `enabledForSite` is true?

Comment: @RobinSchambach I want the latter, i.e. "all sites where enabledForSite is true".  The available sites can be retrieved using the getSupportedSites method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally untested but this should work

```
$enabledSiteIds = (new Query())
    ->select('siteId')
    ->from('{{%elements_sites}}')
    ->where([
        'enabled' => true,
        'elementId' => $elementId
    ])
    ->column();
```

You might want to join the `elements` and `entries` table in order to gain only elements where `elements.enabled` is true too (and check the expiry date), otherwise you'll receive disabled entries

Answer (score 1):

`$entry->getLocalized()->all()` will return an array of the same entry in other locales.  You could map that into a list of all of the site's handles:

```php
array_map(function($entry)  {
  return $entry->site->handle;
}, $entry->getLocalized()->all())
```

[Docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-element.html#public-methods)